# Enhancing OpenCV findTransformECC with a mask

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-registration

I'd like to register two images with the `findTransformECC` function offered by `OpenCV`.

My images have a irregular surrounding border I'd like to mask. I worked with feature based matching functions from the Feature2D-library and findHomography which worked quite well and offered a masking of image parts that should not be taken into account for estimating the transformation parameters.

`findTransformECC` doesn't offer such a masking, therefore I clipped the images by a centered rectangular shape. The clipped  images are aligned very well after transformation. Since I'm using `MOTION_EUCLIDEAN` - which is just a rotation and translation - I thought I could use exactly the same transformation matrix for aligning the images of original extent - but I was proved wrong. The images aren't correct aligned after transforming them. The orientation of transformed images seem to be OK but images show a wrong translation. My thought was when input-images are clipped with exactly the same centered clipping-area and the rotation is performed around the center the final translation operation should fit as well?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In `OpenCV 3.*` masking is possible with the [`findTransformECC`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga7ded46f9a55c0364c92ccd2019d43e3a) function. You can use the argument `inputMask` in the function.